# Does source transformation in circuit analysis work the other way around?

Tags: source

We all know that the source transformation shown in the first picture below is valid. But does it also work in reverse, as shown in the second picture? (because I use proteus to draw second picture, so you are regardless of value of current,voltage and resistor in second picture)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is it ok for source transformation in second picture

No, the left-most source is indistinguishable from a 1A current source and the right-most source is indistinguishable from a 1V voltage source.

Placing a resistor in series with a current source does not change the overall source impedance since a current source has 'infinite' source impedance.

To see this, note that the open-circuit voltage for the left most source is 'infinite' while the short-circuit current is 1A.  But this is identical to a 1A current source without a series resistor.

Placing a resistor in parallel with a voltage source does not change the overall source impedance since a voltage source has zero source impedance.

To see this, note that the open-circuit voltage for the right most source is 1V  while the short-circuit current is 'infinite'.  But this is identical to a 1V voltage source without a parallel resistor.

Thus, the left-most source is not equivalent to the right-most source.

Answer (score 2):

A constant current source has infinite impedance - that is to say it looks like an infinite impedance in series with an infinite voltage source. Adding 10k in series with an infinite impedance makes no difference - it's still a constant current generator and unrecognizable (electrically) from the same source with nothing in series.

Imagine you wanted to build a 1mA amp current source from just a voltage source and a resistor. You want the 1mA to flow for loads between zero ohms and 1kohm. If the voltage source were 10 volts and the series resistance were 10kohm, for a shorted output, 1mA would flow and for a 1k output load 0.909mA flows - not a terrible current source but not that great either.

But what if the voltage source were 100 volts in series with 100k? Same story for a zero ohm load - 1mA flows but, for a 1k load 0.9901mA flows. This of course is a better current source and if you take it to extremes (not that this is possible in practise), a 1 million volt source in series with a 1 Gohm resistor would produce a current of 0.9999990 milli amps into a 1kohm - this would be a great current source but of course is impractical.

I'm using these examples to demonstrate that a real constant current source *can* be regarded as an infinite voltage source in series with an infinite resistance and if you accept this then you begin to realize that any amount of resistance placed in series with it makes no difference.